# Find the radius of convergence of summesion (n=0 to ∞)(an*x^n), where an=[sin(n!)/n!] and ao=0?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, formal-power-series

found a question like this and there are four options

1. R>=1
2. R>=2*pi
3. R<=4*pi
4. R<=pi, where R denotes radius of convergence. I've tried hard but cant get it how to show in equality. Also there is question in my mind that among four options if the series is not converge at the end point can we discard that option. I'm not sure abut this since we know if anywhere "<" holds we can say "<=" holds, but the converse is'nt not true.

Please help to find the solution. Please answer it in the answer section rather comment. Thanks in advance.

I repost this because dont know why my previous post is locked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because your  "previous post" with the same question has a correct answer. At the moment it does not look locked to me.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker sir in previous post there were two different answers, so I was commenting in the comment section, but suddenly it was locked dont kno why.

Comment: @Bolker sir as per I know I can comment over a  answer if there is anything confusing to me.

Comment: @Bolker sir please dont close this, I really need this answer

Comment: You already have an answer at the previous question. The radius of convergence is infinite (the series converges for all values of $x$). Answers (1) and (2) are both correct. SInce there are two correct answers I suspect you may have miscopied the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Hadamard formula gives
$$0 \leq R^{-1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{\sin n!}{n!} \right|} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{n!} } = 0. $$
Hence the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: 1337 then which option is/are correct?

Comment: You don't need that fancy formula. Just compare to the series for $e^x$ directly. That's what your inequality does.